# Understanding signed vs unsigned comparison

Tags: c++, underflow

Can somebody tell me why the *if* condition is false?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int a;
    unsigned int ua;

    a = -1;
    ua = a;

    cout << "ua: " << ua << endl;
    if (ua != -1)
        cout << "Is unsigned" << endl;
    else
        cout << "Is signed" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I mean, here ua == int_max_value, it's NOT -1, but when I run this, the output is

> Is signed

Comment: `-1` is converted to `unsigned int` for that comparison.

Comment: if -1 is converted to unsigned int, How can it hold -1? I mean, -1 IS signed :S

Comment: `-1` is converted using two's complement arithmetic, resulting in `UINT_MAX`.  It's just that C++ has a very strong "tendency" to convert everything into unsigned integers (the exact rules for when this happens are rather complex; see the C++ standard for details).

Comment: @harryPoker: It doesn't. But it becomes signed again for the conversion!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`!=` and `==` on arithmetic types perform what is known as the *usual arithmetic conversions* on their operands. As relevant here, given one operand of type `unsigned X` and one operand of type `signed X`, where `X` is one of `int`, `long` and `long long`, the usual arithmetic conversions convert the signed operand to the unsigned type before the comparison takes place.

Hence, when you compare `ua` (of type `unsigned int`) and `-1` (of type `signed int`), `-1` is converted to type `unsigned int` (conceptually, by adding 2<sup>32</sup> to it, assuming 32-bit `int`), and the result compares equal to the value of `ua`.

Comment: Great! Now my mind can rest in peace :)

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior, `!=` will perform the *usual arithmetic conversions* on it's operands if they are arithmetic types. This is covered in the draft C++ standard section `5.10` *Equality operators* which says:

> If both operands are of arithmetic or enumeration type, the usual
>   arithmetic conversions are performed on both operands; each of the
>   operators shall yield true if the specified relationship is true and
>   false if it is false.

in this case this will lead to the integer promotion which will see `-1` converted to unsigned int. This is covered in section `5` paragraph *10* which ends up saying:

> Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank
>   greater than or equal to the rank of the type of the other operand,
>   the operand with signed integer type shall be converted to the type of
>   the operand with unsigned integer type.

Comment: Note that the particular paragraph quoted changed in C++14, but the behavior remains the same. The relevant paper is [N3624](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3624.html).

Comment: Also, the conversion of `-1` to unsigned is not integral promotion.

Comment: @T.C. C++14 is a simpler quote ... wrt to the integral promotions section `5 p 10` says `Otherwise, the integral promotions (4.5) shall be performed on both operands`

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour And if you look at the section cited, integral promotions don't apply to operands whose type is already `int`. The conversion to `unsigned` happens after the integral promotions (if any) are applied.

Comment: @T.C. in C99 and C11 it actually says `All other types are unchanged by the integer promotions.` So I have always thought of it as a promotion even though no change is required but perhaps my interpretation is incorrect.